# Is there a Netbeans/PHPStorm plugin for writing/refactoring to PSR-1/2-compilant code (like phphint.org)

Tags: php, netbeans, coding-style, phpstorm

As the title says:

**Is there a Netbeans/PHPStorm plugin for writing/refactoring to PSR-compilant code ?**

[phphint.org](http://www.phphint.org) does exactly that, but offers only an online-copy&paste-tool, not an IDE-integrated real time solution.

What exactly i'm searching for is:

1. "real time" PSR-code checking while typing
2. reformating/refactoring projects to fit PSR (1/2) coding guidelines (as far as possible)

*In case you are wondering what i'm talking about:
[PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/1/) and [PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/2/) are Coding Guidelines published by the big PHP guys.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For PhpStorm code formatting can be set to PSR1/PSR2 simply:
`File -> Settings -> Code Style -> PHP -> Set From... -> Predefined Style -> PSR1/PSR2`

Details are on the [JetBrain](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/11/more-php-formatting-options-and-bundled-code-styles-for-ps/)'s web site too.

And use `Ctrl + Alt + L` to reformat code.

Answer (score 5):

Just have a look at Fabien Potenciers CS fixer at https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer - I cannot tell you about the quality of the output, but as this seems to be a one time task, I don't think you'd need a plugin for this.

PHPStorm does format your code well to PSR standards by default, and it will also refactor stuff like missing curly braces for one-line if structures etc.

Comment: PHPStorm does/can add missing curly braces for one-line structures.

Comment: As it turns out, phphint.org already uses the PHP-CS-Fixer internally. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the 2nd thing you ask, actually it's already built in Netbeans, you just have to [configure it properly](http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2013/03/24/configuring-netbeans-for-psr-1-and-psr-2-coding-guidelines/) and hit ctrl+shift+F.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer  - we need to use external  tool in phpStorm
- step by step explanation  to set it up on PHPStorm :

before we adding tool : we need to install php-cs-fixer globally

command line run : `composer global require fabpot/php-cs-fixer`
 once Installed  you can test it by entering
command line run : `php-cs-fixer`

should give something like this 
[image: what you see in command line]

once all good - 
- go to PHPStorm 
- go to settings 
- External tools 
- add new tool

add the following as per image below

[image: phpstorm new external tool settings]

Program : `/Users/seramo/.composer/vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer` (global path to php-cs-fixer- you can navigate and select right path for you )

Parameters:  `fix $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ --level=psr2` ( this is command to execute on file  )

Working Directory : `$ProjectFileDir$`

now save and apply.

in you file - menu -tools - External Tools - php-cs-fixer

running this  should  fix  you file to PSR-2 Standards.

additionally,  you can assign key to run this tool.